# Add url alias with parameter (?foo=bar)

Tags: 7, uri

I need to create urls aliases like this:

```
/mypath?foo=bar&foo2=bar2 (source) -> /foo/bar (alias)
```

via standard drupal alias url add (admin/config/search/path), but when I insert that link in the source path textfield I receive an error about not existent source path. But the path is correct (it works).

How can I resolve it? Only via direct db query?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get that error is that the form validation handler verifies the source entered in the form is a valid menu path, using [drupal_valid_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_valid_path/7).

Setting the path alias directly in the database would cause errors, as the source of the path alias is used to set `$GET['q']`, in [drupal_path_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_path_initialize/7), which contains the following code.

```
$_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);
```

In your case, `$_GET['q']` would be set to mypath?foo=bar&foo2=bar2. All the functions that use `$_GET['q']` expect it to the in  the format path/subpath; the presence of the query parameters would cause errors. See for example the code executed by [menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7).

Using a custom module, you could implement [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7), and [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7). The first would transform foo/bar in mypath, setting `$_GET['foo'] = 'bar'`, and `$_GET['foo2'] = 'bar2'`; the second would transform mypath in foo/bar, when `$_GET['foo'] == 'bar'`, and `$_GET['foo2'] == 'bar2'`.